# Handling JSON encoded parameters in PHP in every format

Tags: php, json, post

I am passing parameters by POST and the parameters are JSON encoded. Later I capture the parameters and decode it in a PHP file as follows:

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$entityBody = json_decode($entityBody, true);
```

But the problem is that it only works only when the keys are in double quotes like following:

```
 {
 "id": "5",
 "name": "abcd",
 "imei": "1234"
}
```

When the keys are in single quotes like following the above code does not work.

```
{
 'id': "5",
 'name': "abcd",
 'imei': "1234"
}
```

I am new to Json and PHP. So if anyone gives me idea about how to handle all such cases I will be really grateful.

Comment: you can run a filter to change `'` to `"` before you run json_decode, or you can ensure the origin data is sent correctly

Comment: AFAIK single quotes are not valid JSON, so fix the code that posts the data.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. Could you please give an example?

Comment: @DevZer0: That would be hard. What if there's a single quote somewhere inside a string value? Or an escaped single quote in a key?

Comment: What you show isn't valid JSON. Single quotes are not allowed for enclosing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All strings in JSON **must** be double quoted. Single quoted strings or keys are not valid JSON. Ideally you should not bother with invalid JSON. That's what *standards* are for, so we can all work with a *standardized* data format and don't need to guess.

Comment: Is there any function in JSON or in PHP so that I can make the JSON parameters valid if the encoding is wrong as above?

Comment: No, because what you're working with **is not JSON.** It's some format you(?) made up that is not JSON, so there's no existing function to work with it. Make sure you get valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You might find JSON Lint a useful tool:  http://jsonlint.com/

You can copy/ paste JSON text into it and it will tell you whether its valid or not and, if not, what to correct.  I always use this first when I get stuck with some JSON.